# Use angular directive only once

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I'm using a directive on the body tag to capture global events such as mousedown, mouseup, scroll etc. I was wondering if there is a possible way to allow the usage of an angular directive only once (kind of the singleton concept) or alternatively if a directive can be used only by a certain html tag (in my case the body tag).

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('app.helper', [])
.directive('globalEvents', ['$document', function($document) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('mousedown', function(e) {
      // some action
    });
    $document.bind('scroll', function(e) {
      // some action
    });
  }
}]);
```

**View:**

```
<body global-events>
...<div global-events></div><- is it possible to disallow this or any other usage of the directive
</body>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "only once"? If you put it only in the body of your page then it'll be applied only once, on the body tag (that is, assuming you only have one body tag, which is the standard for html pages)

Comment: If somebody tries to add the directive to another element. I am aware that I won't use it multiple times. This is kind of a concept question if it is possible to have this kind of behaviour.

Comment: add a condition `if element === body`

Comment: one way to do it would be to check the tag name, using jquery: element.prop("tagName")=="BODY"; (tagName returns tag names in capital). Otherwise you can put a flag in your code, the first time you set the variable to true and then if the flag is true you don't add the events again

Comment: but if I would use a directive on multiple DIV tags how does the check for a tag name prevent multiple usage of the directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about implementing this on run like

```
angular.module('app.helper', []).run(['$rootElement', function (root) {

    root.on('mousedown'...
}]);
```

Comment: I tested that seems like a proper alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Check the name is `body`:

```
angular.module('app.helper', [])
  .directive('globalEvents', ['$document', function($document) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (element[0].localName === 'body') {
        element.bind('mousedown', function(e) {
          // some action
        });
        $document.bind('scroll', function(e) {
          // some action
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: This works for the body tag I know. This was more of a general question. If I apply a directive to a div for example this approach wont work because multiple div tags can be used on the view.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to do a check inside your directives to be run only once you can do this:

You can set your directive as a named function and then add a parameter to it as if it was a javascript object (which, in fact, is) this way you can hold a variable that can tell you wheter the directive has been run once already or not and it can be used on any tag, even a tag different than a body, and make sure events are registered for that tag only

```
angular.module('app.helper', []).directive('globalEvents', ['$document', globalEvents]);
function globalEvents($document) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if(globalEvents.first){
    element.bind('mousedown', function(e) {
      // some action
    });
    $document.bind('scroll', function(e) {
      // some action
    });
    globalEvents.first = false;
    }
  }
}

globalEvents.first = true;
```

EDIT: without using named function

```
angular.module('app.helper', [])
.directive('globalEvents', ['$document', function($document) {
  var first = true;
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if(first){
      element.bind('mousedown', function(e) {
      // some action
    });
    $document.bind('scroll', function(e) {
      // some action
    });
      console.log("first");
      first = false;
    } else {
      console.log("second"); 
    }
  }
}]);
```

See on this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/sdK9Mcme19EtnQAw1zOq?p=preview

Comment: Is that possible without the usage of globalEvents outside the directive.

Comment: I get a TypeError: Cannot set property 'first' of undefined on the assigning of the first property.

Comment: I have made another edit and put a plunker as example. By the way I have noticed that this will work on the innermost element rather than the first element in the code

Comment: Thanks again. The innermost...so this is not working properly you are telling me?

Comment: not the way you want it to work, this has to do with the way angular parses directives. There could be a solution in a similar way i have posted here (probably using postLink: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile see the priority section) but i'm not able to work on it at the moment, i'm sorry